# Program parameters for anjuta

Tags: unix, installation, ubuntu-10.04, c

I have recently installed Anjuta.

I don't know what parameters should be passed in order to run the program after clicking on Run -> Execute.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a cursory look an anjuta, the normal workflow seems to be to create a project (which you've done already), and use commands in the “Build” menu to compile. The “Run / Execute” command is there to run your program once it has been compiled: `./test`.

If you're new to C development (or even new to C development on unix), I don't recommend anjuta's default project, which is very complex. If you must use anjuta, use a Makefile project, and add `-O` to the `CFLAGS` line in the Makefile (without `-O`, gcc doesn't emit some important warnings).